# Service reference works for windows form but doesn't work for class library

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, class-library, windows

I have two applications. One of them is a windows forms application and other one is a web application which use a class library. I use a web service(WCF). When I give this web service as service reference to my windows form application everything is fine. But when I give it as service reference to class library, I have this error '`No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ...`'

I give the reference as the same way to these two projects. What should I do?

Comment: What kind of hosting you follow ? IIS or In Process. What kind of binding does it supports ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you cannot configure your WCF service through a configuration file coming from your class library.

Add a `web.config` with the proper WCF configuration (similar to the one in the `app.config` of your winforms project) in your web application assembly.

Comment: Do you mean, I should add wcf service to my web app instead of class lib?

Comment: @cagin No, you can add the service reference to the class lib, but the configuration of the service must be located in the executable assembly (either the winforms or the webapp assembly)